# how to keep elements of a list based on another list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have two lists looking like:

```
list1 = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e','e','g','g']

list2 = ['a','c','z','y']
```

What I want to do is to keep all those elements of list1 that are also in list2.
the outcome should be:

```
outcome= ['a','a','c']
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj One liner HW problems can be solved on SO I guess :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao but we can achieve the result without using itertools..

Comment: Great question. Personally, using numpy may be the best way. The numpy.isin function is fast even the two lists are large. Check the following link for more details. > https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `in` operator, you can check whether an element is in a seqeunce.

```
>>> list2 = ['a','c','z','y']
>>> 'x' in list2
False
>>> 'y' in list2
True
```

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list1 = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e','e','g','g']
>>> list2 = ['a','c','z','y']
>>> [x for x in list1 if x in list2]
['a', 'a', 'c']
```

But `x in list` is not efficient. You'd better convert `list2` to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) object.

```
>>> set2 = set(list2)
>>> [x for x in list1 if x in set2]
['a', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Third alternative: using `filter()`.

Comment: `list(filter(list2.__contains__, list1))`

Comment: @falsetru Won't that return the opposite of what the OP returns?

Comment: @BhargavRao, Both (The code in the answer and in the comment) returns `['a', 'a', 'c']`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I got confused.

Answer (score 7):

From Python 3 onwards use [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list1 = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e','e','g','g']
>>> list2 = ['a','c','z','y']
>>> list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x:x not in list2,list1))
['a', 'a', 'c']
```

The `list` call is necessary as `filterfalse` returns an `itertools` object.

You can also use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in list2 , list1))
['a', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

One alternative approach with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

np.asarray(list1)[np.in1d(list1, list2)].tolist()
#['a', 'a', 'c']
```