# For each item in list L, find all of the corresponding items in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for a fast solution to this Python problem:
- 'For each item in list L, find all of the corresponding items in a dataframe column (`df [ 'col1' ]).

The catch is that both `L` and `df ['col1']` may contain duplicate values and all duplicates should be returned.

For example:

```
L = [1,4,1]
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,1,4,4], 'col2': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The desired output would be a new DataFrame where df [ 'col1' ] contains the values:
`[1,1,1,1,4,4,4]`
and rows are duplicated accordingly.  Note that 1 appears 4 times (twice in L * twice in df)

I have found that the obvious solutions like `.isin()` don't work because they drop duplicates.

A list comprehension *does* work, but it is too slow for my real-life problem, where `len(df) = 16 million` and `len(L) = 150000`):

```py
idx = [y for x in L for y in df[df['col1'].values == x]]
res = df.loc[idx].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is basically just a problem of comparing two lists (with a bit of dataframe indexing difficulty tacked on), and a clever and very fast [solution by Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162293/keep-all-elements-in-one-list-from-another-using-sets/59583307#59583307) almost works for this, except that duplicates in `L` are dropped (it returns `[1, 4, 1, 4, 4]` in the example above; i.e., it finds the duplicates in `df` but ignores the duplicates in `L`).

```py
train = np.array([...]) # my df['col1']
keep = np.array([...]) # my list L
keep.sort()
ind = np.searchsorted(keep, train, side='left')
ind[ind == keep.size] -= 1
train_keep = train[keep[ind] == train]
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial data:

```
L = [1,4,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3,4,1,4,4] })
```

You can create dataframe from L

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
```

and merge it with initial dataframe:

```
result = df.merge(df2, how='inner', on='col')
print(result)
```

Result:

```
   col
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    4
5    4
6    4
```

Comment: This was extremely fast -- which makes sense since `merge()` is optimized code.  Should have thought of that myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC try:

```py
L = [1,4,1]
pd.concat([df.loc[df['col'].eq(el), 'col'] for el in L], axis=0)
```

(Not sure how do you want to have indexes- the above will return a bit raw format)

Output:

```py
0    1
4    1
3    4
5    4
6    4
0    1
4    1
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Reindexed:

```py
pd.concat([df.loc[df['col'].eq(el), 'col'] for el in L], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

#output:

0    1
1    1
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    1
6    1
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This idea makes sense but it was very slow compared to merge().

Comment: I was thinking about it - probably it would depend - what's the size of ```df``` and what's of ```L```